# Using Ajax to determine different results in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

HTML CODE

```html
<div class="card text-center pricing-card mb-20">
 <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
  <?php 
   $gbewas = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM price");
      while($okks = mysqli_fetch_array($gbewas))
   {    ?>
 <li class="list-group-item d-block text-left">
 <input type="radio" name="dep" id="btn-login" value="10">
 <span style="font-size:16px; margin-left:10px"><?=$okks['plan']?></span>
 </li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
</div>
          <!--- SHOW RESULT--->
 <input type="text" class="error" id="logerror">
```

jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn-login").click(function() {
    var price = $("input#btn-login").val();
    $('#logerror').input(price);
  });
});
```

I need solution to this code. 
First issue, I have 4 rows in price dbTable and it fetch out the 4 rows correctly, but if I click on each/different radio buttons it always show the first input value as the result.

Second Issue, The result is not showing in input format

```html
<input type="text" class="error" id="logerror">
```

But show in div format

```html
<div class="error" id="logerror"></div>
```

Comment: id="btn-login" should be unique or use class name to select it

Comment: If you want the price in the text input `$('#logerror').val(price);`

Comment: Using this `$('#logerror').val(price);` solved second issue. thanks and what of first issue

Comment: Are you getting the first row 4 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems - your `id`s are all the same, so jQuery will pick the first `#btn-login` each time.  But you're using the same value (10) for each input anyway, so what's the difference?

Assuming your database has a `[price]` column, let's use that as the value; and let's get the price of *just* the element that was clicked.

```php
while($okks = mysqli_fetch_array($gbewas))
{    
  ?>
  <li class="list-group-item d-block text-left">
    <input type="radio" name="dep" class="btn-login" value="<?= $okks['price'] ?>">
    <span style="font-size:16px; margin-left:10px"><?=$okks['plan']?></span>
  </li>
  <?php 
}
```

Note that we're using `class` instead of `id`, since `id` must be unique. We'll do so in our JavaScript, as well:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-login").click(function() {
    var price = $(this).val();   // the clicked element
    $('#logerror').val(price);   // val(), not input()
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. While generating the list of radio buttons, you were assigning the same id to all the input radios. While you might want to give a common class to all of them, if you need to be able to target each element, you have to give different id to all of them. I've assumed you have some "id" column as well in your price table( or you can use some other identifier which uniquely identifies a row) as part of the id.

```
<div class="card text-center pricing-card mb-20">
 <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
  <?php 
   $gbewas = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM price");
      while($okks = mysqli_fetch_array($gbewas))
   {    ?>
 <li class="list-group-item d-block text-left">
 <input type="radio" name="dep" class="btn_login" id="btnLogin_<?=$okks['id'] ?>" value="10">
 <span style="font-size:16px; margin-left:10px"><?=$okks['plan']?></span>
 </li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
</div>
          <!--- SHOW RESULT--->
 <input type="text" class="error" id="logerror">


<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro|Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Ajax post
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".btn_login").click(function() {
               var price = $(this).val();
               $('#logerror').val(price);
                });
            });
    </script>
```